# Parse JSON with Python and remove ' " and /

Tags: python, json

I'm importing data from MySQL with Python and returning the data as JSON to a Google map to plot the point and add a description to the point.

However, I noticed that if a user enters data for the point like this

"This is really amazing it's so cool!"

I end up with JSON that looks like this

`[{"description" : "This is really amazing it/'s so cool! }]`

which my map doesn't like. I'm wondering if anyone can explain how to remove special characters from the JSON so if the user entered the line above it would be returned as

`[{"description" : "This is really amazing its so cool! }]`

Everything works great without the single, double quotes, slashes etc. I've tried manually removing the special charters and everything works flawlessly!

Comment: Why doesn’t your map “like” that? Maybe you should fix that problem. Or fix the problem of (forward?) slashes somehow making it into your JSON. Hard to give advice without seeing the code that inserts the entered data, selects it, and serializes it to JSON, though.

Comment: What's happened to your closing quote?

Comment: Have you checked out, whether mysql is escaping quotes, when you are storing it in mysql ?

Comment: The string you pasted is not even valid json.

Comment: Oh sorry about the formatting on the JSON, I just typed it free-hand to convey the example - the map won't place markers if the JSON contains single quotes, it messes it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your double quote will be escaped with an slash.

```
payload = {'description': '"This is really amazing its so cool!"'}
json_str = json.dumps(payload)
# json auto add a slash to escape double quote
print(json_str) # => {"description": "\"This is really amazing its so cool!\""}

# Extract the json string will auto remove the slash
# You don't need to handle them manually
extracted_payload = json.loads(json_str)
print(extracted_payload['discription']) # => '"This is really amazing its so cool!"'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Just a quick question why do I get responses that look like this then `[{u'description' : u'This is really amazing its so cool!'}]` why did the "u's" just show up?

Comment: Ok, you're correct! I think the real issue lies in how I'm "asking" for the data from MySQL. Thanks again.